# Calling Authentication Function in react-native

Tags: javascript, function, authentication, react-native

I am setting up a basic authentication screen for my app.
What I have going on right now is a button calling a function called `auth`
My problem is when I click on the button, in turn calling the function, nothing in my function seems to be executed.
Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  TextInput,
  StyleSheet,
  Alert,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Dimensions
} from "react-native";
import { Button, Text } from "native-base";


let width = Dimensions.get("window").width;
let height = Dimensions.get("window").height;

export default class Login extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Login to Aeries"
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isAuthed: false, username: "", authError: false, password: "" };
    this.auth = this.auth.bind(this);


    const showAlert = () => {
      Alert.alert(
        'There was an error loging in. Please check your username and password and try again.'
      )
    }
  }

  auth(){

    //do auth 
    this.setState({ authError: false,isAuthed: false });

    if (this.state.isAuthed === false && this.state.isAuthed === false && this.state.username == "admin" && this.state.password == "admin") { // authentication is successful
      this.setState({ isAuthed: true });
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Grades")
    } else { // auth error
      this.setState({ authError: true,isAuthed: false });
      this.showAlert
    }

  };
  render() {
    const { showAlert } = this.state
    return (
      <View style={styles.wrapper}>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.loginContainer}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="school email"
            keyboardType="email-address"
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            placeholderTextColor="white"
            style={styles.input}
            value={this.state.username}
          />

          <TextInput
            placeholder="password"
            secureTextEntry
            autoCorrect={false}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            placeholderTextColor="white"
            style={styles.input}
            value={this.state.password}
          />

          <View style={{
            flexDirection: 'column',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            margin: 12
          }}>

            <Button
              primary
              onPress={this.auth}
            >

              <Text> Login </Text>

            </Button>
          </View>

        </KeyboardAvoidingView>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  loginContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: width - 42,
    backgroundColor: "#bdc3c7",
    borderRadius: 9,
    marginTop: 21,
    marginBottom: 21
  },

  input: {
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    color: "#2c3e50",
    backgroundColor: "#95a5a6",
    margin: 12,
    height: 42,
    width: width - 69,
    borderRadius: 3
  },

  logo: {
    width: 231,
    height: 231
  },

  wrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginTop: -21
  },

  loginButton: {
    borderRadius: 3,
    marginTop: 9,
    marginBottom: 21
  },
  error: {
    color: 'red',
    textAlign: 'center',
  }
};
```

What should be happening when I click the button is it should be calling the `auth` function

The auth function should check if the username and password are both `admin` and if so navigate to the screen called `Grades`
(btw I am using react-navigation)

If the username and password are not 'admin' then an alert should show up saying the authentication was unsuccessful.

Thanks in advance. Let me know if you would like me to append any other code.

Comment: Unnecessary arrow function will slow down your application.

Comment: setState is asynchronous. Use callback to execute state related controls. Also combine setState. You don't need to separate them.

Comment: And you should set multiple things at once like this this.setState({ test: true, test1: false }); because setState will fire render when it is called.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong, do this

Bind the function in constructor

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.auth = this.auth.bind(this);
}
```

set function like this

```
auth() {
   // Your chunk of code
}
```

The button should be like this

```
<Button onPress={this.auth} />
```

If there is any issue let me know in the comment section!

Check this [live demo](https://snack.expo.io/@raajnadar/alert-on-click)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Just a note for anyone else, move your function out of the constructor.

Comment: There's one thing wrong though Raaj, now my showAlert variable in the `auth` function throughs an error

Comment: No, Binding should be done inside the constructor its a good practice according to facebook..!

Comment: Hmm. When I had the function in the constructor it wouldn't work. So I moved it out and now its fine.

Comment: When I click the button the variable `showAlert` cant be found. How do I fix this?

Comment: How are you trying to access the variable?

Comment: I'm just calling it in the function by giving its name. Just like in the question. So just `showAlert`

Comment: Try doing `this.showAlert` and bind the function and remove the arrow function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173716/discussion-between-joshkmartinez-and-raaj-nadar).